# Distinguishing between "through which" and "during which"

Tags: vocabulary

Would you please correct me in choosing the words and arranging them?

> Taking into account the people's state of the household , we should conduct research **during which or through which** faithfulness to the individual people in exchange for one another will be detected.

By the phrase "the people's state of the household", I mean: the situation, circumstance, or mood which household or each of the members of household have.

By "conduct research", I mean: we are going to do research.

What kind of research? The research through which we will find how faithful the people are to one another.

Comment: "in exchange" doesn't sound right; it sounds as though you're swapping them in and out to see what happens if you have Paul in the household instead of Jimmy. "people's state of the household" is also awkward.

Comment: I would substitute "faithfulness to" for "faithfulness in exchange for" as you did in your explanation.  As for "the people's state" , it sounds like a Communist country comprising one household!

Comment: Any other idea?

Comment: You might want to look at [Reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_%28social_psychology%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one main question here: do I use *during which* or *through which*? Well, both would be accepted and mean roughly the same thing, but there are a few differences. *During which* means that whilst data is collected, you will actively be analyzing the data to find results: during the research.

On the other hand, *through which* means that you are simply using the research to find something out. It doesn't give an indication of when you used to data to come to a conclusion.

As I said though, both will mean roughly the same thing.